# How to delay an button to be pressed again in ios

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have some buttons on my view that play different sounds, the problem is that i need to each of them to not be pressed again until it ends, and to not press another button while another one is playing the sound..

Each button has a (`IBAction`) that plays a systemid.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a `Bool`variable having name `isPlayingSound` and on each button click u can  check `if(isPlayingSound)` then return; `else isPlayingSound = YES;` and on completion of sound playing you set `isPlayingSound = NO;`

Comment: i know how much time each sound play, but i dont know how to change it for false after the time..

Comment: kindly accept my answer also.. so that other can get benefit from same..:)

Comment: there are two ways for doing u can simply use AVAudioPlayer then their  are delegate methods for completion.. or if you want to play system sound then you can simply add a selector after delay to make it false..

Comment: @user3800220 Which class your are using for playing the sound?

Comment: @jailani AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h

Comment: If yes set AVAudioPlayerDelegate as your class and implement the following method - *(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag*. In this method *isPlayingSound = NO;*

Comment: yes my code its like : `-(IBAction)ActionSound:(id)sender {
    
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    
    
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}`